# Trouble understanding how to make github API call via python requests

Tags: python-3.x, api, python-requests

I have been spending some time learning how APIs work for a project I am working on.

I have been using the requests library to do so, and it has been very helpful. Right now I am working with the github api - https://api.github.com/

I ran into a problem when trying to make a call from this specific section of the API - [Github-API-Call](https://api.github.com/users/%7Buser%7D/repos%7B?type,page,per_page,sort%7D)

The following is what I tried:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/users/{user}/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}', auth = ('user', 'pass'))
```

When I make an attempt at checking the status code though with,

```
r.status_code
```

I get returned 404. I noticed that the URL looks strange, I was hoping that somebody might be able to let me know exactly what is going wrong, or explain why the URL looks strange in this example.

Really appreciate somebody taking the time out to explain it.

Comment: `{user}` is meant to be replaced by a github username.
`{?type,page,per_page,sort}` means you can add `type`, `page`, `per_page` and/or `sort` as query parameter(s).

Comment: check out this `https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos?page=3&per_page=1` ... this user is `octocat`, Github's official username, we fetch the repositories of this user one in each page and we are interested in page #3